# What is this "periodic" sequence called?

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic, logarithms, exponentiation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I came across this weird "periodic" sequence (containing only natural numbers) where the first 15 elements are

$$1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8.$$

The sequence is not finite, and to grows to a power of 2 and then resets to 1. If the sequence grows to $2^k$ ($k \in \mathbb{N}$) it will grow to $2^{k + 1}$ after resetting to 1.

Basically, the sequence is made up of "blocks" where the $n$th block contains all natural numbers from $1$ to $2^n$, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I have a couple of questions about it.

1. Do these type of sequences have a name? I would really love to learn more about them.
2. An explicit formula that I have managed to find , by guessing and running code, is

$$a_{n} = 1 + (n \text{ mod } 2^{\lfloor \log_{2}n \rfloor}), \text { where n $\geq$ 1}.$$
I haven't actually *proven* that this formula expresses all elements in the sequence, how would one even approach it? I've tried with induction, but it feels like something is missning, like a recursive formula for the sequence.

Comment: Have a look at https://oeis.org/A062050 and the references and links given there.

Comment: It should not be difficult to see why the formula is as it is. Given an $n$, the way to determine the $n$-th term of the sequence, at least algorithmically, would be to first find the longest, complete sequence preceding it. Note that $1+2+2^2+\dots+2^{r}=2^{r+1}-1$, so you find the largest $r$ such that $2^{r+1}-1\le n$, and conclude that the $n$-th term must be  $n-(2^{r+1}-1)$

Comment: I would expected $1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8$ but not $1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8. $ I would abandon the formula.  Because it is not very clear to me by what rule the next numbers of this series proceed .

Comment: @lonestudent Seems to me to go up to the next power of 2 before resetting. That also includes the initial 1, which is then immediately followed by a second 1. I think those two initial 1s break the pattern you say you would expect. Of course, if the OP knows that this is how it works, they ought to have clarified.

Comment: Hey @Arthur, what should I have clarified? I don't understand.

Comment: If you know the pattern that the sequence follows, it would've been nice if you could put that in words next to the sequence, rather than assuming we pick up on the system from only reading the first few terms (which clearly not all of us do on our first try). Or if you don't know how it continues, you should specify that you don't know, and instead you're assuming it keeps following the system you think it follows.

Comment: @Arthur, I understand. Will describe how the sequence continues. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Arthur Yes, indeed, then it seems clear to me . In the sequence I propose, the end of each $n$th block contains consecutive natural numbers, ending in $2n$ (except the first term ) instead of $2^n$ .

Comment: @lonestudent Why would you expect with $1,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$? It seems natural to you have blocks that end in $1,2,4,6,8$ that in $1,2,4,8$? Do you really think that "even numbers with $1$ prepended" is more natural than "powers of $2$"?

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, I exactly expected like that.  I left out the first term, for instance, defined it as $a_1=1$.  Then I expected for the end of each *block* to end with $2n$ .

Comment: @Academic I don't really understand your reasoning. Why do I have to find longest, complete sequence preceding the $n$th term to determine it? I would love to learn some more.

Answer (score -1):

1. I don't know of any name for this kind of sequence; perhaps someone else does.
2. You can't "prove" that this is the right formula, because the sequence *could* continue with
   $$
   1,1,2,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots
   $$
   What you *can* do is observe that your solution gives the correct answer for all the examples actually shown, and perhaps argue that it's about as simple a formula as you could hope to get for such a thing. Anything beyond that is a statement about psychology rather than mathematics, I'm afraid.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear what continuation OP has in mind.

Comment: I agree. But "what OP has in mind" isn't something I can prove anything about. It's also, arguably, culturally determined. (What's the next number in the sequence 18, 23, 28, 34, 42, 50, ...? 59, of course --- those are the stops on the uptown #1 train in New York City.) Similarly, the sequence 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  ... has, as its 105 element, the number "2", because $a_n$ is the maximum coefficient in the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial. Many a math professor has teased a class with that one...

Comment: @lonestudent, hey, I used your explanation for the sequence. Thanks!